# Formulas not working until clicking "Enable Editing"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, exceljs

I'm using exceljs for my project to manipulate an excel file in my React app. It works as expected but when users download the file, the formulas in the file does not calculate until users click on "Enable Editing". This is a problem because our users will mostly use ipad, and when they download from the ipad, it doesn't even show the option to "Enable Editing". Is there a way to recalculate the worksheet before downloading?
Here is the code:

```
const ExcelJS = require("exceljs");

const handlePrintExcel = async () => {
        try {
            const response = await fetch("/test.xlsx");
            if (!response.ok) {
                console.log("Network response error");
            }
            const blob = await response.blob();
            // Read the Blob using ExcelJS
            const workbook = new ExcelJS.Workbook();
            workbook.xlsx
                .load(blob)
                .then(async (wb) => {
                    const worksheet = workbook.getWorksheet("Sheet1");

                    const cell_f8 = worksheet.getCell("A1");
                    cell_f8.value = 123;
                    const cell_a2 = worksheet.getCell("A2");
                    cell_a2.value = 123;                    

                    workbook.properties.readOnlyRecommended = false;
                    workbook.properties.date1904 = false;

                    workbook.security = {
                        lockWindows: false,
                        lockStructure: false,
                        workbookPassword: null,
                        workbookAlgorithmName: null,
                        workbookHashValue: null,
                    };

                    workbook.calcProperties.fullCalcOnLoad = true;

                    // Write the changes to a buffer
                    const buffer = await workbook.xlsx.writeBuffer();
                    return buffer;
                })
                .then((data) => {
                    // Create a new Blob with the updated data
                    const updatedBlob = new Blob([data], {
                        type: "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet",
                    });
                    // Create a URL for the Blob
                    const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(updatedBlob);
                    // Create an anchor element to trigger the download
                    const anchor = document.createElement("a");
                    anchor.href = url;
                    anchor.download = `Test.xlsx`;
                    // Trigger the download
                    anchor.click();
                    // Revoke the URL to release resources
                    window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
                })
                .catch((error) => {
                    console.error("Error processing Excel file: ", error);
                });
        } catch (error) {
            console.error("Error converting Excel file into Blob:", error);
        }
    };
```